# Mongoosastic reference not saved

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate, mongoosastic

I have this:

```
const ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    projectId: String,
    author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', es_indexed: true, es_schema: getUserModel().schema, es_select: 'first_name last_name email' },
    participants: [String],
    category: String,
    title: String,
    description: String,
});
```

and User looks like this:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    userId: String,
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
});
```

in my database I see this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58d4456fd3d52632e010d377"),
"author" : ObjectId("58ce87e7f86e5d36f6ccfb81"),
"projectId" : "J0MXYM1S872Y3",
"category" : "gaming",
"title" : "The Project",
"description" : "This is the project.",
"participants" : [ ],
"__v" : 0
}
```

`ObjectId("58ce87e7f86e5d36f6ccfb81")` is a valid id, I can find a User with this id.

on elastisearch head I see this:

```
"_source": {
"projectId": "J0MXYM1S872Y3",
"author": { },
"participants": [ ],
"category": "gaming",
"title": "The Project",
"description": "This is the project."
}
```

Why is author empty???

**EDIT**

I added this at the bottom:

```
ProjectSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    esClient: esClient,
    populate: [
        {path: 'users', select: 'first_name last_name email'}
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So after a day of debugging the mongoosastic.js I have found that it needs to be populated, and as populate path I should not put the collection name but a name of the field like this:

```
ProjectSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    esClient: esClient,
    populate: [
        {path: 'author', select: 'first_name last_name email'}
    ],
});
```